# query - excluding prefix from field results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I wrote query that returns result based on debug field that is set on 0 or 1. 
On the given result I have some strings that include prefix *dev_* that I want to remove from the results. How can I do that?

This are my results..

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "serviceUrl": "dev_url",
            "serviceUsername": "dev_username",
            "servicePassword": "dev_password"
        }
    ],
    "message": null
}
```

And this is the code..

```
 if ($debug = true) {
        $query = $this->getClientRepository()
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c.serviceUrl', 'c.serviceUsername', 'c.servicePassword')
            ->where('c.debug = :debug')
            ->setParameter('debug', $debug);

    }else {

        $query = $this->getClientRepository()
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c.SecondServiceUrl', 'c.SecondServiceUsername', 'c.SecondServicePassword');
    }

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: use plane php to modify results before output, doctrine has nothing to do with it

Comment: Or don't select them, eg `somestring not like 'dev_%'`